# A measure-preserving system is ergodic iff $A_N(f)=\to\int fd\mu$ as $N\to\infty$ for all $f$ in a dense subset of $L_\mu^1$.

Tags: ergodic-theory

> (GTM 259 Exercise 2.5.3.) Show that a measure-preserving system $(X,\mathscr B,\mu, T)$ is ergodic if and only if $A_N(f)=\frac 1N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f\circ T^n\to\int fd\mu$ as $N\to\infty$ for all $f$ in a dense subset of $L_\mu^1$.

---

The "only if " part is clear by Birkhoff, but how to show the "if" part? Also, I have no idea how to do the "only if" part without using Birkhoff's theorem

Comment: Is the convergence pointwise?

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not sure actually. The authors didn't make it clear enough, but I would assume it in $L_\mu^1$ because it is mentioned that $f$ in a dense subset of $L_\mu^1$.

Comment: if it's $L^1$ convergence, then you get $A_N(f) \to \int f d\mu$ for all $f \in L^1$, by a trivial density argument.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't see why it is trivial. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Take $f$. Take $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ with $A_N(f_n) \to \int f_n$ in $L^1$ as $N \to \infty$ for each $n$. Then $||A_N(f)-\int f||_1 \le ||A_N(f)-A_N(f_n)||+||A_N(f_n)-\int f_n||+||\int f_n - \int f||$. Note (1)$A_N(f)-A_N(g) = A_N(f-g)$ and (2) $||A_N(h)|| \le ||h||$. Now just choose parameters ($n$ and $N$) correctly.

Comment: @mathworker21 Why do you have $A_N(f_n)\to\int f_n$ in $L^1$? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: We're assuming we have $A_N g \to \int g$ in $L^1$ for all $g$ in a dense subset of $L^1$. Maybe I should have made it clear that I'm saying the following: if $A_Nf \to \int f$ for all $f$ in a dense subset, then $A_N f \to \int f$ for all $f$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Aha! I see. Do you know how to prove the "only if" part without Birkhoff?

Comment: Birkhoff is pointwise convergence, right?

Comment: Also, I think it's trivial to show $A_Nf \to \int f$ in $L^2$ if $f = g-Tg$ for some $g \in L^\infty$. And doesn't convergence in $L^2$ imply convergence in $L^1$, since we're in a finite measure space?

Comment: @mathworker21 While, yes it is. But it also claims that if it is in $L_\mu^1$, then converge to a $T$-invariant function $f^*\in \mathscr L_\mu^1 $, and $\int f^*d\mu=\int f d\mu$.

Comment: @mathworker21 But how can we assume $f=g-Tg$?

Comment: re your first (i.e. second to last) comment: but that convergence is pointwise convergence still. re your second (i.e. last) comment: we wish to show convergence for a dense subset; that dense subset will be the set of all $\{g-Tg\}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Though I haven't read the proof of Birkhoff, at least Theorem 2.30 on GTM259 claims the convergence in $L^1$. And why $\{g-Tg\}$ is dense?

Comment: I'm sure there is some theorem that ensures convergence in $L^1$. Also, I should have said the span of constants and the set $\{g-Tg : g \in L^\infty\}$ is dense. It is certainly dense in $L^2$; I'm sure your book proves that (the proof is that if $h$ is in the orthogonal complement, then $h-Th$ is orthogonal to every $g \in L^\infty$, forcing $h-Th = 0$, meaning $h$ is $T$-invariant, which, by ergodicity, means $h$ is constant, so $h$ is orthogonal to itself, which means it's $0$). Therefore it is dense in $L^1$ (if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$).

Comment: Sorry, neither did I find this proof in my book, nor did I understand your reasoning... Why do you claim $h$ is orthogonal to itself? And do why all these have anything to do with density in $L^2$?

Comment: It is 100% in your book (whatever book it is); look at proof of mean ergodic theorem. $h$ is in the orthogonal complement of [span of constants and $\{g-Tg\}$], so it's orthogonal to constants. I had already shown $h$ is constant, so it's orthogonal to itself. What all of that has to do with $L^2$ is that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, so, to show that a certain subset of $L^2$ is dense, it suffices to show that its orthogonal complement just contains the zero vector, which is what I showed.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you! I will check again.

Comment: is all good now?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, actually I find it easy to show the "if" part. Just assume $Tf=f$ then we can infer that $f$ is constant by the condition.

Comment: how? dont u first need what i said about going from dense to all L^1?

Comment: Yes, of course we need this part.